# XSLT select all text and specific node

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

I would like to select all text from an XHTML file except all hyperlink elements which are needed to be printed fully:

**XHTML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<html>
   <body>
      <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
      <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
      <a href="www.link.com">This is a link.</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

Desired output:

```
This is a paragraph. This is another paragraph. <a href="www.link.com">This is a link.</a>
```

I am using the following XSLT, but getting no results:

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="text"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="ancestor-or-self::text()">
      <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="a">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help on this will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the output method. See also: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#built-in-rule

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but neither isn't working for me.

Comment: @BernatL What exactly does "*isn't  working*" mean? -- P.S. See it working here: http://xsltransform.net/94rmq68

Comment: I was getting _null_ result, but maybe it was a processor error. I am checking your solution in different XSLT processors and looks like it is now.

Comment: Ok, it was a processor issue indeed. Thanks again, your solution works fine. @michael.hor257k